# how to define the cell valuetype of a new datagridviewcell to add into a datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, types, cells

have a datagridview with different types of columns.
now I want to add a row, consisting of different cells. I can not define a cell as a datagridviewcell but must define it as a textboxcell or a comboboxcell etc. But I want to let that depend on the type of column.. I do not get it to work.

the data comes from a dataset, but only takes the data from the datatable which is needed in the datagridview. Therefore I can not bind the datagridview to the datatable.

```
   For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim rij As New DataGridViewRow
        For i = 0 To dgOrder.ColumnCount - 1
            ''Dim cel As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell 'does work but Must already define value type......
            ''Dim cel As  dgOrder.Columns(i).CellType 'does not work
            ''Dim CEL As DataGridViewCell '' does not work because value is not assigned
             ''CEL.ValueType = dgOrder.Columns(i).CellType ''doesn't help
              columntext = dgOrder.Columns(i).Name
             ''CEL.Style = dgOrder.Columns(i).DefaultCellStyle
             CEL.Value = dr.Item(columntext)    
             rij.Cells.Add(CEL)
        Next
       dgOrder.Rows.Add(rij)
  Next
```

Anybody an idea how to use a dim cel as datagridviewcell or how to define cel with the correct datagridviewcelltype?

Comment: _Therefore I can not bind the datagridview to the datatable_ - can you explain why you cannot? Because `datagridView.DataSource = yourDataTable` must work and it will be much easy solution then adding rows manually

Comment: While I do not need to display all items... I made this some time ago and I think I did it mainly for taht reason. Now I want to make it more dependend from the columns in the datagridview so by adding a column, it does automatically change all the data. if a field does not exists in the datatable, it will be added in another piece of script.  but before we go into this discussion, it must be possible to make a datagridviewcell???

Comment: Your code looping all rows and all columns - trying add cell for every value in the DataTable. So `datagridView.DataSource = yourDataTable` will do same thing with one line. If you don't want show all columns in DataGridView, then set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False` and add columns you need in designer. Remember set `Column.DataPropertyName = columnNameInDataTable`

Comment: but also people need to manually give new data into the datagridview,.. this is only a art of the code.. It seems we go in circles but nobody just seems to know how to make a datagridviewcell......For this small change I do not want to go into a big reteting of the software to see if there was another reason why I did not make the binding at that time. Lets pretend I did that for a reason... It still must be possible??

Comment: in the meantime I found out why I choose to use it unbound and not bound.  I use a rag and drop function on the dtagridview ( people can change the order of the rows) and I do not get this to work with a bound datagridview...

Comment: You don't need create a new `DataGridViewCell` - you need only create new DataGridViewRow and add new values ther - cell will be generated automatically.

Comment: that's how it was. I am making the creation of the datagridview automatically so that when the columns ar changed, I do not have to make sure that this datagridview creation is also changed. this to make it easier to develop and to minimise the amount of errors when 1 "bulding block" of the program  is changed..